# How to display the datatype of a variable in a python file

Tags: python, function, variables, types

I know about the built-in function **type()**

It works fine in the *interactive mode* of python. But when you try and use it in a **.py** file, nothing gets displayed.

Which method should I use if I want to check the data type inside a python script/file?

Comment: What do you mean *"nothing gets displayed"*? Displayed *where?!* Have you tried e.g. `print(type(whatever))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is not the `type` function, but rather how you are generating output. In interactive mode, stuff that you type on the console generates output, but when scripting it does not. You need to explicitly tell it to output:

```
print(type(x))
```

Comment: ahan! Thank you so much. I'm a beginner hence a bit confused between the interactive mode and actual scripts. Will keep that in mind from now on :)

Comment: Glad I could help ;) please take the time to accept the answer. Thanks!